# Does starcraft 2 take advantage of both my processors? Or how can I make it?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have two processors (both at 2.66ghz). I can have the textures run at high (that should only depend on your video card, right?) But I can't even turn shaders from low to medium without my framerate going from 33 to 14. To me, the shaders are what make the game start to look great. Is there a way to make Starcraft 2 use my other processor?

Comment: [Shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaders) are mostly calculated in the GPU, so it's likely that your graphical card is the bottleneck here, improving CPU won't help a lot, I think.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://www.techspot.com/review/305-starcraft2-performance/page13.html) performance report for Starcraft 2, the game is only capable of using two cores. If both of your processors each have multiple cores, only two cores will be used by Starcraft 2.

Comment: So is there anything I can change in some settings or something? Or does it just run as good as it's going to?

Comment: You don't have to do anything for it to use two cores, it is turned on by default.